# How to acquire access-token silently for a background task

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365, access-token, azure-ad-msal

My console application needs to access a user's emails, download all the attachements, and process them in some way.
The application is running in a scheduled task, and set to run-as the user.

I was planning on using Microsoft.Graph, but first I need an access-token, using MSAL.net, but I just don't understand how it works.

```
var tenantId = "xxx-xxx-xxx";
var clientId = "yyy-yyy-yyy";
var clientSecret = "zzz-zzz-zzz";
var scopes = new List<string> { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

var client = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                //.WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
                .Build();

var request = client.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes);
var token = request.ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken;
```

Using this code gives me the following exception:

> The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

However, the `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` class does not provide the `.WithClientSecret(clientSecret)` method.
It is available with the `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` class, but then there is no `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes)` method. I could use the `.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account)` method, but how do I get the `IAccount` required?

How do I acquire an access-token without user interaction for the logged-in user?

---

(edit)More info:

That user/email only exists to receive emails containing new orders that I need to create in our ERP. So every hour, the scheduler launches the application, looks at all the new emails received, download the attachement, and creates the new orders in the ERP.

I was using MailKit with username/password, and it worked fine, but now that we need to use modern authentication, it won't log in anymore. That is why I am transition the app to use `Microsoft.Graph`.

I have created the App Registration in Azure, that is where I get the TenantID, ClientID, and ClientSecret.

Comment: Maybe you could just use App Password with your existing MailKit client. What is app password: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944

Answer (score 1):

> The application is running in a scheduled task, and set to run-as the user.

If your trying to use UserCredentials from the logged on user then you app would be using the delegate permissions. So first thing

```
var scopes = new List<string> { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
```

Is for Application permissions (Client Credentials flow) and also won't generate a Token that would be usable in the Graph (eg from the Graph a Client Credentials scope would be "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"). For Email your scope for delegate permissions should be something like

```
var scopes = new List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read };
```

With the clients you can have a public client (which don't use a client secret) or a confidential client there is good explanation of the differences
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications

With the Authentication flow your trying to use IWA this requires a public client https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#integrated-windows-authentication-iwa

So your application registration must allow this eg

[image]

Answer (score 0):

console application + microsoft graph api  ==>  we need to use client credential flow

You can generate access token then create a http request manually, try code below to get access token.

```
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;
```

If you want to graph SDK, then no need to generate a stand alone access token, just give the authorized provider, code should look like:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var res = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Messages["{message-id}"].Request().GetAsync();
```

By the way, using client credential flow requires to add application permission. For [get email mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions), it requires `Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read`.

[image]